# Build Data Loader job

Tags: data-loader

How to build a data loader job to run in background that will upsert account and contact and update a field on contact.

Comment: Require a quick reply .....

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate a bit more here.  Are you simply asking how to use the data loader for upserts and updates, or are you asking about having scheduled jobs to perform updates periodically.  Please elaborate and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to do this using batch/command line mode of Data Loader
1. it will do an upsert on Account                        2. then upsert on contact
3. with the flag set to true

Comment: Did you look at this article?
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

Comment: Yes i have already taken a look at this article. I Just wanted to know if u want to set a checkbox field to true when upserting contact                                  1.Is this to be given in csv or                            2. Its possible to give it in process-conf.xml file as we specify the externalid field